# How to make ParseKit recognise newline characters?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, parsekit

I'm trying to make ParseKit's Tokenizer recognise newline characters and no other whitespace characters.

Also, the examples show how to make it recognise comments starting with a hash but the functions created seem to apply only to single chars. I'd like to make PK recognise comments that begin with two dashes ('--') and end in a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you are looking for the way to make `PKTokenizer` recognize `--` as a single-line comment marker (like in AppleScript), this is it:

```
PKTokenizer *t = [PKTokenizer tokenizerWithString:str];

// make sure `--` is recognized as a single multi-char token
[t.symbolState add:@"--"];

// designate `--` as a single-line comment marker
[t.commentState addSingleLineStartMaker:@"--"];

// make sure `commentState` handles `-` chars first (to check for comments)
[t setTokenizerState:t.commentState from:'-' to:'-'];
```

This is explained more fully in the [Tokenizer documentation](http://parsekit.com/tokenization.html).